# Find All $x$ from $0$ - $200$ where $f(x)$ is a whole number

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

I know that there has to be work done on this somewhere, but I can't find it. Does anyone know how to solve a problem like this? It's seems likes its going to be fairly discrete. Sorry if it's an easy one.

> Find all $x \in [0, 200]$ where $f(x)$ is a whole number.
>
> $f(x) = M/(60x)$
>
> $M$ = Given Constant
>
> $M$ is a real number
>
> $x$ is a real number

Comment: So, you are just asking that $x$ is a divisor of $M/60$?

Comment: @mvw - updated question for you all number in this problem are real.

Comment: @Paolo Leonetti - i don't think so.  If x is just a divisor the range i need could be all real numbers, in this case i can only accept whole numbers as an answer to f(x).

Comment: HINT: Start by drawing down the graph of $f$ for some values of $M$. Do you find a pattern?

Comment: @Crostul when I graph I get the same pattern in quadrants 1 & 3.  The graph is not continuous, is doesn't pass through 0.  Y approaches 0 as x increases.

Comment: @mvw I see what your saying.  How does this affect the solution. As we approach 0 y will go to infinity.  I could solve this by limiting my domain further and/or proving that f(0) is infinity through series.  Let me know if I'm bing dense here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $M \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = M / (60 x)$ we want to determine the solution set
$$
S = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}, x \in [0, 200] \}
$$

Let $I = (0, 200] \subset \mathbb{R}$ be your set of inputs, which does not include $0$, as $f(0)$ would require division by zero, which is undefined.

Then your set of outputs is $f(I)$ and its subset which contains only whole numbers is $F = f(I) \cap \mathbb{Z}$.

We want to know which members of $I$ end up in $F$ via $f$, so we make use of the inverse map $f^{-1}$ to find out the solution set $S$:
$$
S = f^{-1}(F) \cap I = f^{-1}(f(I) \cap \mathbb{Z}) \cap I
$$
where we restricted to $I$ as $f^{-1}$ might be multi-valued, possibly introducing elements outside $I$. We now try to invert $f$ to determine $f^{-1}$:
$$
y = f(x) = \frac{M}{60} \frac{1}{x}
$$
We need to solve for $x$ and this can be done by multiplying both sides by $x$ and dividing both sides by $y$. 
$$
x = \frac{M}{60} \frac{1}{y}
$$
The division is only valid for $y \ne 0$ which requires $M \ne 0$.
In other words we found out $f^{-1} = f$ if $M \ne 0$, $f$ is its own inverse if $M \ne 0$.

**Case $M=0$:**

In this case we have $f(I) = \{ 0 \}$ and $F(I) = \{ 0 \} \cap \mathbb{Z} = \{ 0 \}$. So $f^{-1}(\{ 0 \}) = \mathbb{R}$ and $S = \mathbb{R} \cap I = I = (0, 200]$.

**Case $M > 0$:**

Then $f(200) = M/12000$ and $f(\epsilon) = M / (60\epsilon) \to \infty$ for $\epsilon > 0$ and $\epsilon \to 0$. Then 
$$
F = f(I) \cap \mathbb{Z} =
[M/12000, \infty) \cap \mathbb{Z} =
\{ k \in \mathbb{Z} \mid k \ge \lceil M /12000 \rceil \}
$$
and because $f^{-1} = f$ for $M \ne 0$ we get the set
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(F)
&= f(F) \\
&= f(\{ k \in \mathbb{Z} \mid k \ge \lceil M /12000 \rceil \}) \\
&= \{ f(k) \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}, k \ge \lceil M /12000 \rceil \} \\
\end{align}
where the maximum element is
$$
f(\lceil M / 12000 \rceil)
= \frac{M}{60 \lceil M / 12000 \rceil}
\le \frac{M}{60 (M / 12000)}
= 200
$$
while the other elements decrease but stay positive.
This gives the solution set
\begin{align}
S 
&= f^{-1}(F) \cap I \\
&= \{ f(k) \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}, k \ge \lceil M /12000 \rceil \} \cap (0, 200] \\
&= \{ f(k) \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}, k \ge \lceil M /12000 \rceil \}
\end{align}

**Case $M < 0$:**

Then $f(200) = M/12000 < 0$ and $f(\epsilon) = M / (60\epsilon) \to -\infty$ for $\epsilon > 0$ and $\epsilon \to 0$. Then 
$$
F = f(I) \cap \mathbb{Z} =
(-\infty, M/12000] \cap \mathbb{Z} =
\{ k \in \mathbb{Z} \mid k \le \lfloor M /12000 \rfloor \}
$$
and because $f^{-1} = f$ for $M \ne 0$ we get the set
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(F)
&= f(F) \\
&= f(\{ k \in \mathbb{Z} \mid k \le \lfloor M /12000 \rfloor \}) \\
&= \{ f(k) \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}, k \le \lfloor M /12000 \rfloor \} \\
\end{align}
where the maximum element is
$$
f(\lfloor M / 12000 \rfloor)
= \frac{M}{60 \lfloor M / 12000 \rfloor}
\le \frac{M}{60 (M / 12000)}
= 200
$$
while the other elements decrease but stay positive.
This gives the solution set
\begin{align}
S 
&= f^{-1}(F) \cap I \\
&= \{ f(k) \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}, k \le \lfloor M /12000 \rfloor \} \cap (0, 200] \\
&= \{ f(k) \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}, k \le \lfloor M /12000 \rfloor \}
\end{align}

**Example:**

$M= 164.814$, so we have the case $M > 0$. Then $f(I) = [164.814/12000, \infty) = [0.0137345, \infty)$.
So 
$F = f(I) \cap \mathbb{Z} 
= \{ k \in \mathbb{Z} \mid k \ge \lceil 0.0137345 \rceil\}
= \{ k \in \mathbb{Z} \mid k \ge 1 \} = \mathbb{N}.$

Further
\begin{align}
S
&= f^{-1}(F) \\
&= f(F) \\
&= f(\mathbb{N}) \\
&= \left\{ f(k) \mid k \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \\
&= \left\{ M/(60 k) \mid k \in \mathbb{N} \right\}
\end{align}

This works because the set of all
$$
x_k = f(k) = M/(60 k) \quad (k \in \mathbb{N})
$$
has the largest element $x_1 = 164.184/60 = 2.747 \in (0, 200]$ and the other $x_k$ are smaller and positive, so all $x_k$ are in $(0,200]$ as asked for.
Further we have
$$
y_k = f(x_k) = f(f(k)) = k \in \mathbb{N}
$$
so because $f$ is its own inverse ($M$ was not zero) we end up with whole numbers $y_k = k$.

Here is a session I had with my friend Ruby. First I told her the value of $M$ and what the function $f$ is:

```
irb(main):001:0> M = 164.184
=> 164.184
irb(main):002:0> def f(k)
irb(main):003:1> return M/(60.0 * k)
irb(main):004:1> end
=> :f
```

Then I asked here to calculate a couple of the $x_k$ from the solution set $S$:

```
irb(main):005:0> x1 = f(1)
=> 2.7364
irb(main):006:0> x2 = f(2)
=> 1.3682
irb(main):007:0> x3 = f(3)
=> 0.9121333333333334
irb(main):008:0> x10 = f(10)
=> 0.27364
irb(main):009:0> x100 = f(100)
=> 0.027364
irb(main):010:0> x1000 = f(1000)
=> 0.0027364
```

Indeed, all calculated $x_k$ are from $(0, 200]$.

Then I asked her to calculate the $y_k = f(x_k)$ values:

```
irb(main):011:0> y1 = f(x1)
=> 1.0
irb(main):012:0> y2 = f(x2)
=> 2.0
irb(main):013:0> y3 = f(x3)
=> 3.0
irb(main):014:0> y10 = f(x10)
=> 10.0
irb(main):015:0> y100 = f(x100)
=> 100.0
irb(main):016:0> y1000 = f(x1000)
=> 1000.0
```

We can see that every $y_k$ is a whole number. So it seems to work for the values we tried.

Comment: Alright, I believe I understand your set, but how would you evaluate this for a given M.  Can you provide an example or perhaps direct me to a resource.  Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: M = 164.814   Thanks

Comment: thanks.  I've been taking some time to go over this, but admittedly, my set theory is not so strong.  I understand that Set N must contain all values, but how do I actually evaluate and return every value

Comment: You just evaluate $f(1)$, $f(2)$, $f(3)$, .. and so on. For this particular $M$ all natural numbers are used.

Comment: So your suggesting I do this computationally? I don't understand how this only returns inputs whose outputs are whole numbers.  If i'm just being dense, could you let me know what fields of mathematics your implying here so I could do some research.

Comment: I added a short computational session to show that the solution set $S$ for your $M$ has the desired properties for all the values that I tried. The field of mathematics used is just the algebra to come up with an inverse for $f$ and a bit of set notation to define the involved sets.. Depending on $M$ the solution sets differ as showed above. In each case you end up with infinite many elements from the interval $I=(0, 200]$, which all yield integer values when fed into $f$. (Because there are infinite many solutions in each case, you can not compute all of them in finite time :-)

Answer (score 0):

If $M=0$ all $x\in\>]0,200]$ are feasible.

If $M\ne0$ then both $M$ and $-M$ admit the same set $S$ of feasible $x$-values.

If $M>0$ and ${M\over 60x}=k\in{\mathbb Z}$ for some $x>0$ then necessarily $k\geq1$, and $$x=x_k:={M\over 60 k}\ .$$
We now have to check for which $k\geq1$ the number $x_k$ is feasible. The condition $$0<x_k={M\over60 k}\leq200$$ is fulfilled as soon as $k\geq {M\over12\,000}$. It follows that the set $S$  is given by
$$S=\left\{{|M|\over 60 k}\>\biggm|\>k\in{\mathbb N}, \ k\geq\left\lceil{|M|\over 12\,000}\right\rceil\right\}\ .$$